# How to get data from config file (config.json) in real time in settings.py file in django

Tags: django, social-auth-app-django

I have a project made in Django. I have only added social auth for login purposes. I want selected emails only to log in to the website. I used `social-auth-app-django` library for social auth and added a variable `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_WHITELISTED_EMAILS` to the `settings.py` file where it contains a list of all the emails permitted for logging in.

My project directory looks something like this:

```
project_parent/
----project/
--------settings.py
--------wsgi.py
--------asgi.py
--------urls.py
----app/
--------models.py
--------views.py
--------urls.py
--------admin.py
----db.sqlite3
----manage.py
----config.json
```

Here is the config file:

```
{
    "OAUTH2": {
        "WHITELISTED_EMAILS": [
            "xyz@gmail.com",
            "abc@gmail.com", 
            "efg@gmail.com", 
            "lmn@gmail.com"
        ]
    }
}
```

In `settings.py` file I have loaded the config file like this:

```
config = open('./config.json',)
data = json.load(config)
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_WHITELISTED_EMAILS = data['OAUTH2']['WHITELISTED_EMAILS']
```

I have made a webpage that takes the new mail id (need to add to the config file) and appends that particular mail id (or a list of mail ids) to the `config.json` file. But now the problem arises, the newly added mails don't reflect directly to the variable defined in the `settings.py` file. For that, I need to restart the code in order to get the latest config file. Every time I add a mail id, I need to restart the code.

I thought to make a database table in my `app` folder and load that table in `settings.py` by import the `model` from `app` folder. But on importing, the terminal raises the error as it says `app is still not loaded` so that I can't use the models inside my app.

Is there a way in which I can directly load the database table without importing the `models.py` file from `app` folder? Or if possible to load the `config.json` file in real-time so that I don't have to restart the code

Answer (score 1):

`settings.py` in Django is loaded once at execution time, we should not change the values during runtime. Although that is suggested by the docs there are ways you can change the settings values during runtime. You can use [django-constance](https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library, and then make a form to update the setting's value during runtime by editing the database value.

Comment: Hey, I explored this library, I was able to add the Constance in the admin panel where I can change the value, add emails to it. But how to get that value in the settings.py file?

Comment: By moving the key to the [CONSTANCE_CONFIG](https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#configuration).

Comment: What does that mean? Which key?

Comment: `"OAUTH2": { "WHITELISTED_EMAILS": [ "xyz@gmail.com", abc@gmail.com", "efg@gmail.com", "lmn@gmail.com" ] }`
Add this into the config as per the docs.

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. For the admin panel to show the config file you have to add something like `CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
    'WHITELISTED_EMAILS': ('', 'Restricted emails'),
}`

Comment: Here the ' ' is the empty space in the field in the config admin panel. What you write there is stored in the Constance database. I want to access that database.